# nhibernate:alternative to Session.IsDirty()

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a piece of code that opens an nHibernate transaction. I only want to do this if the current session is dirty. I was using Session.IsDirty() but I've since found that this flushes an pending SQL statements to the database. Does anyone know of an alternative that I can use that simply checks if there are any pending SQL statements but does not execute them?

Comment: This pattern sounds strange. Did you tried some UnitOfWork?

Comment: It is best practice to wrap in transaction simple reads too. So you should not need that, because everything should be transacted. Not transacting causes the connection to be released after each statement, and may cause the second level cache to cease caching. If you have lock contention troubles or deadlocks when transacting, this usually means something is wrong within the application, like too long transactions, too high isolation levels, or things like "read committed snapshot" not enabled on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension for this: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate. You need to get each EntityEntry from the PersistenceContext and see if it is dirty.